# python, find difference between two unequal lists

Tags: python, list, difference

how to find the difference between to list which have not the same length?

Both lists are normalized.

Comment: Hi @kooper, what have you tried so far? Could you post your code?

Comment: How do you even define "difference"? What should be the result of e.g. `find_difference([1, 4, 5], [5, 7, 1, 11, 5, 1])`?

Comment: Does this code: `list(set([1,2,3]) ^ set([1,2,3,4]))` fulfils your requirement?

Comment: Please when you ask a question provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what discrete difference you're talking about.

If you'd like all elements in A not in B:

```
list(set(A) - set(B))
```

If you'd like all elements not in both lists:

```
list(set(A).symmetric_difference(set(B)))
```

The difference can be seen in this example:

```
In : set([1, 2]) - set([2, 3])
Out: set([1]) 

In : set([1, 2]).symmetric_difference(set([2, 3]))
Out: set([1, 3])
```

Comment: Also - symmetric difference can be written as `(A ^ B)`

Answer (score -3):

[`Functionally`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming),

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], zip(l1, l2)))
```

you can zip the two lists and check if the entires are not the same and filter out to get those differences. You can change this to fit your specific needs such as getting a list of the same length as l1 and l2 but with `True` and `False` if they match or not

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(l1,l2)))
```

Comment: I downvoted, the question is very unclear, but i don't follow your interpretation. It says the lists are not the same length, your use of `zip()` will truncate the longer list, also you're comparing at only the same index, not sure why. For questions like this it might be better just to seek clarity and/or vote to close

Comment: yeah. I did interpret that OP wanted what elements at the same index were different, and that the length inequality meant they were unequal. Still think that is valid in some interpretation - but with such a poor question who knows.

Comment: I think it's still better to opt to downvote the question or flag it as off-topic instead of guessing some possible solution.